# file 'ntwin32.mak' not found error while making files for live555 installation

Tags: windows, nmake, live555

I am following the live555 installation steps from [here](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/#config-windows). and have .mak makefiles in each folder. To make the Makefiles I do : `nmake abc.mak` everytime to get an error  `fatal error U1052: file 'ntwin32.mak' not found Stop.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167842/4788546.

Answer (score 1):

NtWin32.mak and Win32.mak ship with the Windows SDK.  Install from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8442) and then find the files in "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include".  Copy them to all the subdirectories you wish to build.

You will need to build (ie. call namke -f *.mak" in each subdir) from a console *after* calling

```
CALL "%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

No you are not crazy if you are wondering why this popular library has an arcane build process on Windows rather than just using CMake.